# How do I get a pretty URL when creating a link in a Razor View?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm asking how to do a link with `@Url.Action` in a Razor view to make a link like

```
Controller/Action/123
```

I already made `@Url.Action("Action","Controller", new { @ViewBag.ID })` but it makes me a link like

```
Controller/Action?ID=123
```

How do I make a URL without the querystring in the razor view?

Comment: I beleive both are same. MVC internally use `id` even for `/123`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Url.RouteUrl(String, Object)` and not`Url.Action()`

Use the default route name.. which must be `Default` 
so your code should be :

```
@Url.RouteUrl("Default", new {controller = "SomeControler", action = "SomeAction" ,  id = @ViewBag.ID })
```

Doing that will give you url as follows : `SomeController/SomeAction/5` (assuming ID was 5)

This happens because of the by default the project mvc template contains a `Default` route as follows :

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

You can create more fancy urls if you wish or if you need more parameters, by adding more routes into routing table

here's the description : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505215(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: Doesn't answer the OP's question of "I'm asking how to do a link with Url.Action".

Comment: I am sure OP doesn't know about Url.RouteUrl()

Comment: and besides, the url that OP wants can not be created with `Url.Action`

Comment: Sorry, not true.  RouteUrl and Action both render the same value.  The problem had nothing to do with the method he was using and everything to do with the fact that he had not specified the route parameter correctly as I stated in my answer below.

Comment: `RouteUrl and Action both render the same value` ? Please get your basics correct man. You can not have a query string less url with Url.Action if there are parameters in the Url

Comment: `@Url.Action("Details", "Home", new { id = 1})` renders as `/Home/Details/1`.

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
@Url.Action("actionname", "controllername", new { id = ViewBag.Id})
```

I think the problem is just that you haven't specified that the value in your route parameters collection is the "id".  Of course, I'm assuming that you're using the default route configuration in RegisterRoutes.

Answer (score 1):

Tip: you can also use `Html.ActionLink()` which saves you the trouble of creating an `<a>` tag yourself:

```
@Html.ActionLink("linkText", "actionName", "controllerName", new { id = ViewBag.ID }, null);
```

This will generate an `<a>` tag with the `linkText` and the same url as `Url.Action()` which you can see in Jeff's answer.

Note: don't forget to add `null` as the last parameter, otherwise it will use the wrong overload and use the anonymous type as `htmlAttributes`.

Comment: I was about to suggest this as well.  Another option still is Html.RouteLink, which I've heard performs slightly better than ActionLink.

Comment: Yes that's an option too. But personally I prefer this since I don't want to use route names in my view, sometimes I even use `null` for a route name.

Comment: I was voted down too, by the way, even though I provided the only answer that directly answered the original poster's actual question.  SMH

Answer (score -5):

```
@Url.Action("Action/" + @ViewBag.ID,"Controller")
```

Comment: This won't work since it will look for an action called `Action123` for example.

Comment: I have no idea, just tried it on my mvc4 application @Url.Action("Action/" + "123", "Controller") will output /Controller/Action/123 which is what OP is asking for

Comment: I can't imagine that it will work. But even if it does, it's dirty way to do it.

Comment: so do you mean it's a bugs and will be fixed in further release? any reason they don't encode the / character in ActionName ?

Comment: I would say that it is simply not the correct usage of the method.  Not necessarily a bug but it's almost always best to use methods as they were intended to be used.